# using sharedmodule with routerLink attribute

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-router

I have a SharedModule
This shared module has a component with a template where I use [routerLink] attribute. The shared module doesn't define any route but needs to know about routing attributes/services so I can't use forRoot() or forChild().

I define the routes in the **AppModule** with the forRoot syntax.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
    appRoutes,
    { enableTracing: process.env.ROUTE_TRACING }
)
```

If I import the RouterModule in the **SharedModule** I get an error:

```
TestComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: 
StaticInjectorError[Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Router]: 

   imports: [
        HttpClientModule, 
        CommonModule, 
        ButtonsModule,
        RouterModule]
```

The question is how can i pass on the routes from the app module to the shared module. If I define a [routerlink] in a component of the shared module it needs to know about the routes of the appModule.

The shared module needs to know all the attributes/services of RouterModule and needs to know the routes of the app module.

If I just import RouterLink and add it to the shared module it doesn't seem to understand the routes of the app module.

Do I need to do something with a forRoot static method on the shared module?

Thanks

Comment: You could try changing `RouterModule` to `RouterModule.forChild()` and see if that helps.